# Function returns an original value without modifying it

Tags: php

My function `trim_text` would not give the trimmed words when using another function like `dash_text`. BUT giving a string directly to the `trim_text` would work!

```
function trim_text($data, $limit){
    $words  = str_word_count($data, 1);
    $trim = (count($words) >= $limit)? array_slice($words, 0, $limit) : $words; 
    return implode(" ", $trim);
}

function dash_text($data){
    $data = str_replace(' ','-',$data);
    return $data;
}


$title = 'this is a test.';

$slug = trim_text(dash_text($title), 2);
var_dump($slug); //this will not return the trimmed words but instead return `this-is-a-test.`
//should return `this-is`

$slug = trim_text('this is a test', 2);
var_dump($slug); //but this would!
```

Also, if my methods are not the best practice(I'm not talking about security), tell me some suggestions to convert `$title` to lowered, trimmed and dashed string.

Comment: this is my problem: `string(14) "this-is-a-test"`.. should return `this-is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because this line of code:

```
$data = str_replace(' ','-',$data);
```

You are replacing space with dash.

Words separated concatenated by space are different.

e.g. In the string

`this is a test.`, `this`, `is`, `a`, `...` are words

But, concatenated with hypen (dash) are not different.

e.g. `this-is-a-test`

`this-is-a-test` is the only word.

So,

Change

```
trim_text(dash_text($title), 2);
```

To:

```
$slug = dash_text(trim_text($title, 2));
```

Comment: explain why this is the problem

Comment: oh yes that's why. because space in `this is a test` is replaced to dash(`-`), there will be no words to trim. thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `$slug = dash_text(trim_text($title, 2));`

instead of `trim_text(dash_text($title), 2);`

**Explanation**

In your case, the method `dash_text($title)` will be executed first, and it will return `this-is-a-test.`. The method `trim_text` is performed on this string. Hence it will return `this-is-a-test.` since there are no word separators in the input.

On the other hand, `dash_text(trim_text($title, 2));` will perform `trim_text` first and will return `this is`. Then `dash_text` will be performed on `this is` and will return `this-is`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that str_word_count function does not count words separated by "-" as multiple words. See PHP documentation:

http://lv.php.net/str_word_count

> For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters.

Due to the fact that you convert all of the spaces to "-" and then pass the text 'this-is-a-test' to trim_text function, you always get a return value of 1 from str_word_count.

Be careful with the order of functions you call.